# Aether, how to get dependencies with hierarchy

Tags: java, maven, aether

I'm using eather to re-create the same structure of maven dependency:tree within my code.
Following the documentation I found this useful [example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java) which correctly list the same depdendencys as the plugin but it lacks any "tree" information, it's just a flat list.

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    throws Exception
{
    System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------" );
    System.out.println( ResolveTransitiveDependencies.class.getSimpleName() );

    RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

    RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:1.0.0.v20140518" );

    DependencyFilter classpathFlter = DependencyFilterUtils.classpathFilter( JavaScopes.COMPILE );

    CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
    collectRequest.setRoot( new Dependency( artifact, JavaScopes.COMPILE ) );
    collectRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

    DependencyRequest dependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest( collectRequest, classpathFlter );

    List<ArtifactResult> artifactResults =
        system.resolveDependencies( session, dependencyRequest ).getArtifactResults();

    for ( ArtifactResult artifactResult : artifactResults )
    {
        System.out.println( artifactResult.getArtifact() + " resolved to " + artifactResult.getArtifact().getFile() );
    }
}
```

I then wrote another piece of code to retrieve non-transitive dependencies and, invoking it recurively, was able to get a full dependency graph, but without any limitation, so I should implement some filtering/limit routine.

Since I'd like to keep as much as possible the same plugin logic, without introducing "my" filtering, is there any way to adapt the fist example in order to retrieve hierarchy information as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `exactly the same` behavior, as plugin implements, I suggest to look into the plugin's source code [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/tree/trunk/maven-dependency-plugin), so you will not miss any nuances. But the basic approach is to use `collectRequest` to `collectDependencies`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");

    RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

    RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession(system);

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact("org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3");

    DependencyFilter classpathFlter = DependencyFilterUtils.classpathFilter(JavaScopes.COMPILE);

    CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
    collectRequest.setRoot(new Dependency(artifact, JavaScopes.COMPILE));
    collectRequest.setRepositories(Booter.newRepositories(system, session));

    DependencyRequest dependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest(collectRequest, classpathFlter);

    List<ArtifactResult> artifactResults =
            system.resolveDependencies(session, dependencyRequest).getArtifactResults();

//        for (ArtifactResult artifactResult : artifactResults) {
//            System.out.println(artifactResult.getArtifact() + " resolved to " + artifactResult.getArtifact().getFile());
//        }

    //use collectDependencies to collect
    CollectResult collectResult = system.collectDependencies(session, collectRequest);
    DependencyNode node = collectResult.getRoot();
    node.accept(new TreeDependencyVisitor(new DependencyVisitor() {
        String indent = "";
        @Override
        public boolean visitEnter(DependencyNode dependencyNode) {
            System.out.println(indent + dependencyNode.getArtifact());
            indent += "    ";
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean visitLeave(DependencyNode dependencyNode) {
            indent = indent.substring(0, indent.length() - 4);
            return true;
        }
    }));

}
```

[EDIT:]
To include test dependencies, you will need to customize session's depSelector, like this:

```
    DependencySelector depFilter =
            new AndDependencySelector(
                    new ScopeDependencySelector( "provided" ),
                    new OptionalDependencySelector(),
                    new ExclusionDependencySelector()
            );
```

And add classpathFilter to traversing:

```
DependencyFilter classpathFlter = DependencyFilterUtils.classpathFilter(JavaScopes.TEST);

node.accept(new TreeDependencyVisitor(new FilteringDependencyVisitor(new DependencyVisitor() {
    ...
}, classpathFlter)));
```

Still, this will not be exactly as `dependency:tree`, because it will actually list all the jars, that will go to test classpath. But with this you can actually further customize NodeVisitor to filter whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Dzmitry, I just tested this and it seems exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: after some deeper testing, it seems that the suggested code is ignoring [test] scope from my project. With dependency:tree I get `[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test` which is directly declared in my pom While your code is returning `junit:junit:jar:4.12 (compile)` as a transitive dependency of another artifact, then ignoring test one. @dzmitry-paulenka

Comment: Edited answer a bit.

Comment: Hi @dzmitry-paulenka, thanks a lot for your support!
I tried to perform suggested changes, find whole class [here](http://pastebin.com/5dGADZX0)
With this code I got approx 830 dependencies listed, with all scope available. First run took 710 seconds, I suppose to retrieve all information from central repo. A second run took just 32 seconds for the same output.
Dependency:tree list just 125 artifact in 2seconds. Do you know if some documentation on how dep:tree apply filters is available to optimize such long analysis?

Comment: I think this is beyound my knowledge... I suggest to look into the plugin source code..